# Non Real Time Serial Data Plotter

Tags: matlab, arduino, serial-port, pyserial, real-time-data

I'm working on a motion sensor project, and I would like to acquire acceleration data from a sensor (MPU6050) attached to Arduino. So I get the 3 values of acceleration ax, ay and az and  I send them in the USB serial link.

Now I can get the ax, ay, and az values and plot them correctly and all is working good.

THE PROBLEM: is that it's not real-time, ie. when I vibrate the sensor the values don't change simultaneousely like the instant serial plotter of Arduino which I didn't use because I want to analyse these data later in MATLAB (to do pattern recognition tasks so I can distinguish movements).

This is my code, I need to know what part consumes that time and what can I do to overcome this problem?

NOTE: I tried to use also pySerial to acquire data and Matplotlib but I had the same problem, it's not simultaneous.

```
%%real time data plot from a serial port
% Original script written by Moidu thavot.

%%Clear all variables
clc;
clear all;
close all;

if isempty(instrfind) == 0
    fclose(instrfind); % Close com ports
    delete(instrfind); % Clear com ports
end

%%Variables (Edit yourself)

SerialPort='com6'; %serial port
TimeInterval=0;%time interval between each input.
loop=inf;%count values
yMIN = -100;
yMAX = 100;
xWIDTH = 200;
%%Set up the serial port object
s = serial(SerialPort, 'BaudRate', 115200); % setup comport
fopen(s);

time = now;
y1 = 0;
y2 = 0;
y3 = 0;
%% Set up the figure
figureHandle = figure('NumberTitle','off',...
    'Name','Acceleration Plots',...
    'Color',[0 0 0],'Visible','off');

% Set axes
axesHandle = axes('Parent',figureHandle,...
    'YGrid','on',...
    'YColor',[0.9725 0.9725 0.9725],...
    'XGrid','on',...
    'XColor',[0.9725 0.9725 0.9725],...
    'Color',[0 0 0]);

hold on;

plotHandle1 = plot(axesHandle,time,y1,'LineWidth',1,'Color',[1 0 0]);
plotHandle2 = plot(axesHandle,time,y2,'LineWidth',1,'Color',[0 1 0]);
plotHandle3 = plot(axesHandle,time,y3,'LineWidth',1,'Color',[0 0 1]);

%xlim(axesHandle,[min(time) max(time+0.001)]);
%ylim([yMIN yMAX]);

% Create xlabel
xlabel('Time','FontWeight','bold','FontSize',14,'Color',[1 1 0]);

% Create ylabel
ylabel('Acceleration Values','FontWeight','bold','FontSize',14,'Color',[1 1 0]);

% Create title
title('Real Time Data','FontSize',15,'Color',[1 1 0]);

%% Initializing variables

y1(1)=0;
y2(1)=0;
y3(1)=0;
time(1)=0;
count = 2;
while ~isequal(count,loop)

    u = fscanf(s, '%f %f %f');
    y1(count) = u(1);
    y2(count) = u(2);
    y3(count) = u(3);

    time(count) = count;

    xlim([max(time-xWIDTH) max(time)]);

    set(plotHandle1,'YData',y1,'XData',time);
    set(plotHandle2,'YData',y2,'XData',time);
    set(plotHandle3,'YData',y3,'XData',time);
    set(figureHandle,'Visible','on');
    datetick('x','mm/DD HH:MM');

    pause(TimeInterval);
    count = count +1;
end

%% Clean up the serial port
fclose(s);
delete(s);
clear s;
```

[image]

Comment: What of kind of delay do you have? It's simply delay from the sensor movement, or it looks like the data came in chunks with pause between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Get rid of the pause in your while loop. Instead, take a look at what you are reading from the serial port if data is available go ahead with the processing and showing, if not repeat the loop.

2- Use 'drawnow' with 'limitrate' after you set the plots

3- check the baudrate, In MATLAB side you can still increase it. I don't know about the arduino  side

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I tried all the above: - no pause, added drawnow, increased bauderate to 115200, but the graph is still not real-time, there is still a delay between the real motion variation and the plots :'(

Comment: The size of y1,y2,y3 is changing in the while loop. Preallocation can definitely help. Take a look here:https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocating-arrays.html . Preallocate few number of samples for excample 1000, then if you have sample number 1001 throw away sample number 1. In addition, don't update the plots at the arrival of each sample, update the y1,y2,y3 and then every k loop update once the plot. I hope this helps